# Field Calculator: return two or more field value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-2.7

I trying to return three field values in same If Statment and conecate them, but i Get NULL value insted of the conecated fields

```
 getClass (!InDiameter! , !OutDiameter! , !TheridDiameter!, !FREQUENCY! )
     if FREQUENCY== 1:
        return In
     if FREQUENCY== 2:
        return(In &"-"& Out)

     if FREQUENCY == 3:
        return(In &"-"& Out &"-"&Therid)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getClass (In , Out , Therid, freq )
     if FREQUENCY== 1:
        return str(In)
     elif FREQUENCY== 2:
        return (str(In) + "-" + str(Out) )
     elif FREQUENCY == 3:
        return (str(In) +"-" + str(Out) + "-" + str(Therid) )
     else:
        return "other frequency"
```

here is a quick fix. Concantenation in Python uses "+", and I converted your fields to string str() just to make sure they are not numeric (otherwise not necessary)

Comment: In the input parameters, you need to define frequency the same as in the rest of the code; `FREQUENCY` (or change in the code to `freq`).

Comment: it's work but i get zero's (3.0 insted of 3) because i put str for double value

Comment: you can use str(int(In)) in place of str(In)